# The doomsday oracle

Tags: riddle

An oracle proclaims an ominous message:

> Calling for help, something is not right 
>   Justice strikes them down, all in one night 
>   Cry havoc, no one will be left 
>   Run to your homes, downcast and bereft 
>   Kneeling and standing up, one disappears without a trace 
>   In that year this disaster will take place

What year is the oracle talking about?

---

*Hint:*

> Each line (except for the last one) contains three elements. The year does not have thousands of digits.

*Hint:*

> For each line (except for the last one), you just have to start at the beginning and follow the instructions.

Comment: Just to be clear, does "thousands of digits" mean (1) literally thousands of digits, (2) more digits than one would reasonably expect, or (3) a thousands digit? (Perhaps you intended the ambiguity, in which case fair enough.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It was in response to paste's comment and a bit joking, but it means that the year doesn't contain more digits than you would reasonably expect (and therefore it also doesn't consist of literally thousands of digits)

Comment: OK, thanks. (That was my guess at what you meant, for what it's worth.)

Comment: I like this puzzle. Short, clear, and has an "Aha!" solution.

Comment: @DanRussell Tnx! It took some time to get everything in a short riddle without the solution being too obvious, and I'm glad you like it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three elements in each line are:

> The capital letter, a number, and a direction.

If we combine these by

> starting at the letter on a QWERTY keyboard, moving in the direction for the number of keys indicated

we get

> MMXVI, or 2016.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh, yes. Couldn't figure out that third element. Nicely done.

Answer (score 8):

**Partial answer:**

> Each line except the last has a direction in it. Starting with the first, they are `right`, `down`, `left`, `down`, `up`. It's possible that the first one is `not right`, though.
>  Each line also contains a number word or a homophone thereof. Starting  at the top we have `for`, `one`, `one`, `to`, `one` = `41121` (credit to @f'' for pointing out the `for` and `to`)

Possible answer:

> If we match these directions to number on a numpad, we get `62428`

Comment: There are a lot more possible numeric associations too.  "Calling for help" = 911, "one" appears three times.

Comment: And on a keyboard there's a 7 on the "HOME" button (well, usually)

Comment: At this rate, the year will have thousands of digits by the time we're done.

Comment: Your possible answer is not correct, but you are on the right track. Maybe the hint can help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wild guess:

> 74754

And here is my reasoning:

> None of these lines are more then nine words long. So we can't have a 6-digit year. I took the place of the word and counted each word until I stopped at the direction word.

Special case for the fourth line:

> It it in the word `downcast`.